# MathML tag: "stretchy" attribute issue

Tags: mathjax, mathml

I was wondering, in the following example why the [stretchy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Attribute) attribute of `mo` tag is giving similar display. I thought the second `MathML` below (with `<mo stretchy="false">∑</mo>` would display the upper and lower limits on top and bottom of the summation symbol (as shown in figure 2 below). But both the examples (with `<mo stretchy="true">∑</mo>` and `<mo stretchy="false">∑</mo>` respectively) are displaying the limits on sides of summation symbol instead:

**Remark**: I'm using [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)

**HTML with MathML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MathJax TeX to MathML Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>With stretchy="true"</p>
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><msubsup><mo stretchy="true">∑</mo><mrow><mi>k</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>0</mn></mrow><mrow><mi>n</mi></mrow></msubsup><mrow><mfenced separators="|"><mrow><mfrac linethickness="0pt"><mrow><mi>n</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>k</mi></mrow></mfrac></mrow></mfenced><msup><mrow><mi>x</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>k</mi></mrow></msup><msup><mrow><mi>a</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>n</mi><mo>-</mo><mi>k</mi></mrow></msup></mrow></mrow></math>
    <p>With stretchy="false"</p>
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><munderover><mo stretchy="false">∑</mo><mrow><mi>k</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>0</mn></mrow><mrow><mi>n</mi></mrow></munderover><mrow><msup><mrow><mi>r</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>k</mi></mrow></msup></mrow></mrow></math>
</body>
</html>
```

**Display of the above HTML** [using MathJax]:

[image]

**Desired display of second MathML** (with `<mo stretchy="false">∑</mo>`):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the wrong attribute.  It is not `strethy="false"` that you want, but `movablelimits="false"` (or use `<math display="block">` or `<mstyle displaystyle="true">` around the expression).

For example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/mml-chtml.js"></script>

<p>
<b>movablelimits="false"</b>
<br>

<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <munderover>
    <mo movablelimits="false">∑</mo>
    <mrow>
      <mi>k</mi>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mn>0</mn>
    </mrow>
    <mi>n</mi>
  </munderover>
  <msup>
    <mi>r</mi>
    <mi>k</mi>
  </msup>
</math>

</p><p>

<b>display="block"</b>
<br>

<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <munderover>
    <mo>∑</mo>
    <mrow>
      <mi>k</mi>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mn>0</mn>
    </mrow>
    <mi>n</mi>
  </munderover>
  <msup>
    <mi>r</mi>
    <mi>k</mi>
  </msup>
</math>

</p><p>

<b>mstyle displaystyle="true"</b>
<br>

<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mstyle displaystyle="true">
  <munderover>
    <mo>∑</mo>
    <mrow>
      <mi>k</mi>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mn>0</mn>
    </mrow>
    <mi>n</mi>
  </munderover>
  <msup>
    <mi>r</mi>
    <mi>k</mi>
  </msup>
  </mstyle>
</math>

</p>
```

Note, however, that these generate different output.  The first uses a smaller summation sign (since it is in-line math style), the second uses a separate line with the math centered on it, and the third is in-line, but uses the display-mode layout rules.

Comment: Thank you - specially for nice explanation.